# How to disable "5 seconds power button shut off" on a laptop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bios, shutdown

I know this is a pretty dangerous action to do but I'd like to disable the (hardware?) feature that immediately shuts the computer down when you hold the power button for 5 seconds or so.

I have an hp envy x360 15-bq103nl that has the power button on the left side and the power jack on the right side, so when I'm charging the laptop and I want to use portrait mode I have to keep the power jack on top, but doing so cause the power button to press because of the laptop own weight and the laptop to immediately shut down in 5 secs.

Using portrait mode is really useful if I have to read the news, facebook, long mails, or if I have to keep the temperature of the CPU cool because this laptop has a really underpowered heat dissipation system.

The best thing would be to disable it only if I use the portrait mode, so it doesn't interfere with this type of usage.

Is this even possible? 
I know is possible to modify hardware-related options directly from the OS, but I guess this is a big one to modify.

Maybe a modded BIOS? 
(would be great if someone can mod this one so I can undervolt the CPU to make it cooler)

Thanks to everyone in advance, I'm available for any further explanation

Comment: I don't think it's possible to disable it.

Comment: This cannot be handled by OS. Maybe there is a BIOS setting on your m/b which can alter it, but I'm strongly doubt. This is implemented at the hardware level.

Comment: This cannot be done. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/642058/9591612) is same question on SO and have multiple answers. You may find it a good read.

Comment: Sandeep and Akina, thanks a lot for your answers. I'm Italian and my English is really not that good to fully understand the ACPI document. I understood that it is a full hardware feature, or something similar to an embedded system, right? so the only real way (at least for me) to disable this feature is to replace the physical power button with a button that sends a single "impulse" to the motherboard, instead of a long "signal", if I'm not wrong. Unfortunately, I'm not gonna do this because my laptop is still under warranty, and I think this method is REALLY dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

I does not suggest you to do this, if you insist on this, try the following steps.

1. Open `Control Panel`
2. Find and click `System and Security`
3. Find and click `Power Options`
4. On the left hand, you will see `Choose what the power button does` and click it
5. Click `Change settings that are currently unavailable` to be able to change the settings
6. In `When I press the power button`, you can choose Do nothing

[image]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Clever idea, but have you verified that it works for the 4 second hold-down?  I believe that operates at the hardware level, so I'd be surprised if you could change it by an OS setting.

Comment: I knew this software setting and I usually have it set to "do nothing". I often change it to "go to sleep" because at my university we usually leave laptops unattended and it's helpful to be able to put the computer in sleep mode with only one button. However, this setting does NOT disable the "5 seconds to shut down" thing.